# MySQL Random Limit Select with table join

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a simple database (see image) and I'd like to retrieve 10 questions randomly with all their answers (between 2-4 answers per question). I've tried multiple queries but I can't seem to get it right.

Things I've tried:

```
SELECT qa.Answerid,qa.Questionid
FROM question_answer as qa
JOIN (SELECT q.Questionid FROM question q ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 10)
WHERE qa.Questionid = q.Questionid

select *
From question q,question_answer qa,answer a 
where qa.Questionid=q.Questionid and qa.Answerid=a.Answerid
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 10
```

[image]

I need a result like the following:

```
AnswerId         QuestionId       ...        ...        ...
```

With a maximum of 10 random QuestionId and the number of AnswerId will vary depending of how many answer there is for the 10 random questions.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery on `question` to get the 10 questions and then `join` in the answers:

```
select *
From (select q.*
      from question q
      order by rand()
      limit 10
     ) q join
     question_answer qa
     on qa.Questionid = q.Questionid join
     answer a 
     on qa.Answerid = a.Answerid;
```